# Java: Hibernate don't import files

Tags: java, hibernate, config

my Hibernate Config doesn't import any .sql files.
The files are located in `src/test/resources` and the Source in `src/test/java`.

The Part of the Config:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(SomeModel.class);
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
p.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
p.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:test");
p.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "/createdb.sql");
StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(p).build();
this.sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I don't know why he doesn't import the .sql file. I hope that anyone can help me.

Greetings

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081832/hibernate-hbm2ddl-import-files-path-to-the-files

Comment: Is it suppose to use different `.sql` files?

Comment: @ScaryWombat i used the path `p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "/resources/facttable.sql");` but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link [hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files: Path to the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081832/hibernate-hbm2ddl-import-files-path-to-the-files)

The path needs to be pathed as

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/WEB-NF/resources/createdb.sql</prop>
```

or programmatically as

```
p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "/WEB-INF/resources/createdb.sql");
```

Comment: But i haven't a `/WEB-INF/` directory

Comment: Oh OK, not a web application, then try fully pathing the file

Comment: I tried `/src/test/resources/facttable.sql` but it also doesn't work

Comment: do you have a fully path file such as `/src/test/resources/facttable.sql` or is this below your project directory?

Answer (score 0):

Since, your file **facttable.sql** is in src/test/resources folder. You need to use the below code to access it.

```
p.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "src\\test\\resources\\facttable.sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

The import file is looked up from the root resources directory, which is `src/main/resources`.
So, if you put your SQL file in there under folder `sql`, e.g. `src/main/resources/sql/createdb.sql`, then this should work:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">sql/createdb.sql</prop>
```