# `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property stops working if I switch the datasource from `H2` to `postgresql`

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, h2

This is the config of my spring boot app:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class Cfg {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource o = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        o.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        o.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        return o;
    }

    @Bean("entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource myDataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean o = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        o.setDataSource(myDataSource);
        o.setPackagesToScan("fctorial.crossover.entities");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "classpath:/schema.sql,classpath:/data.sql");
        o.setHibernateProperties(props);
        return o;
    }
}
```

And it works as expected, but for some reason, if I change the database to postgresql (via the following patch), the `import_files` aren't executed anymore.

```
@@ -17,8 +17,10 @@
     @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
     public DataSource myDataSource() {
         org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource o = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
-        o.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
-        o.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
+        o.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
+        o.setUsername("saga");
+        o.setPassword("");
+        o.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");
         return o;
     }
 
@@ -28,7 +30,7 @@
         o.setDataSource(myDataSource);
         o.setPackagesToScan("fctorial.crossover.entities");
         Properties props = new Properties();
-        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
+        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
         props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
         props.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
         props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
```

I have this at the top of `schema.sql`:

```
NOT A VALID SQL STATEMENT;
```

The `h2` version of app throws an error at startup but the `postgresql` version starts without an error and malfunctions at runtime because the database isn't initialized correctly.

Note: This codebase is a a full example demonstrating this issue: https://github.com/fctorial/crud

Comment: The code is using Spring Boot for in-memory database things are created automatically by Spring Boot (which you are trying to work around with the import database) not for real database. Also the `schema.sql` doesn't work for postgresql as that doesn't have `AUTO_INCREMENT` you should use a `SERIAL` column instead. That being said if this is Spring Boot (according to the dependencies) you shouldn't be using the `DataSource` at all and let Spring Boot do it. On the `@Bean` method the `close` isn't needed that is detected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help you [hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files: Path to the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081832/hibernate-hbm2ddl-import-files-path-to-the-files/14081863)

The files are used only when creating schema